# If you scp a file over an ssh tunnel does the file get encrypted twice?

Tags: scp, ssh-tunnel

Backgound info:
Server A needs to send data to Server B but I am not permitted to open any additional ports in the firewall between them.  There is an ssh port open, so I chose to send data through an ssh tunnel.  However, I now need to copy files from A to B as well.

Question:
If I scp files from A to B over my existing ssh tunnel do the files get encrypted twice?  Or is scp "smart enough" to utilize the existing tunnel?

I want to avoid the additional overhead of encrypting twice if possible.

Are there other ways to send files over an ssh tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the double encryption (I would guess yes), but why use `scp` over an `ssh tunnel`? `scp` is using an ssh connection, therefore, no problem with firewalls etc.

If you're looking for an alternative, you can use `rsync` over `ssh` with something like the following:

`rsync -avz -e ssh /home/me myname@servername:/some/folder`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a remote server Remy. Remy has an sshd service but is in a network that has no way of routing new connections to it, but Remy can still access the internet.

Let's say you have another (maybe local) server Loco where Loco can receive new incoming connections.

So Remy is configured to establish an ssh tunnel to Loco with `ssh -R 2201:localhost:22 Loco` so that Loco can ssh through the ssh tunnel to remote into Remy.

Now, from Loco, if you scp or rsync or whatever other utility you use, it will double-encrypt that connection when initiated from Loco - PUSH. This is encrypted twice (ssh through sshtunnel)

```
------ <-- ssh -R 2201:localhost:22 Loco ------
 ---------- ssh localhost:2201 --> -----------
  ====== file transfer PUSH >> ==============
 ---------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------
```

One way around this is to remote through Loco into Remy, and scp/rsync/whatever from Remy to Loco's public internet address - PULL. This establishes a new ssh session that is separate from the sshtunnel, where the connection is only encrypted once.

```
------ <-- ssh -R 2201:localhost:22 Loco ------
 ---------- ssh localhost:2201 --> -----------
 ---------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------
-------------- <-- ssh Loco -------------------
  ====== file transfer PULL >> ==============
-----------------------------------------------
```

The maybe less secure way around this is to have a non-encrypted (ftp) service on Remy which only listens on localhost, and include that port in the sshtunnel configuration `ssh -R 2201:localhost:22 -R 2101:localhost:21 Loco'. Then on Loco you can ftp to localhost:2101 to send files through the sshtunnel to Remy.

```
------ <-- ssh -R 2201:localhost:22 Loco ------
  ====== ftp file transfer >> ===============
-----------------------------------------------
```